# Mostrar serie de números en un JTextPane

Tags: java, array, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente código para mostrar números desordenados y luego ordenarlos con el método burbuja:

```
package OrdenamientoBurbuja;

public class OrdenamientoBurbuja extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public OrdenamientoBurbuja() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

int arreglo[];

public void Ordenamiento(){
    int numero= (int) (Math.random()*Integer.parseInt(this.txtNumero.getText()));

    int i=0, cantidad= numero, rango=numero;
     arreglo = new int[cantidad];

    arreglo[i]=(int)(Math.random()*rango);
    for(i=1; i<cantidad; i++){
        arreglo[i]=(int)(Math.random()*rango);
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
            if(arreglo[i]==arreglo[j]){
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int k=0; k<cantidad; k++){
        System.out.print((k+1)+"- "+arreglo[k]+"\n");
        this.numSinOrdenar.setText(((k+1)+"- "+arreglo[k]+"\n"));
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtNumero = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    btnOK = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnOrdenar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    numOrdenados = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
    jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    numSinOrdenar = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Introducir cantidad:");

    btnOK.setText("Ok");
    btnOK.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnOKActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnOrdenar.setText("Ordenar");
    btnOrdenar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnOrdenarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(numOrdenados);

    jScrollPane3.setViewportView(numSinOrdenar);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(txtNumero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 118, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(btnOK))
                        .addComponent(btnOrdenar))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(6, 6, 6)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(txtNumero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnOK))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnOrdenar)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 194, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    this.Ordenamiento();
    this.txtNumero.setText("");
}                                     

private void btnOrdenarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
     for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length-1;i++)
          for(int j=0;j<arreglo.length-i-1;j++)
               if(arreglo[j+1]<arreglo[j]){
                  int aux=arreglo[j+1];
                  arreglo[j+1]=arreglo[j];
                  arreglo[j]=aux;
                  this.numOrdenados.setText(((j+1)+"- "+arreglo[j]));
                  System.out.print((j+1)+"- "+arreglo[j]+"\n");
               }
}                                          

public static void main(String args[]) {

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OrdenamientoBurbuja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OrdenamientoBurbuja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OrdenamientoBurbuja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OrdenamientoBurbuja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new OrdenamientoBurbuja().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnOK;
private javax.swing.JButton btnOrdenar;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
private javax.swing.JTextPane numOrdenados;
private javax.swing.JTextPane numSinOrdenar;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtNumero;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Me podrían explicar porque razón el método burbuja me repite los números y porque razón solo se muestra el último numero de la variable del *for* en vez de mostrarse todo el arreglo en los JTextPane

Answer (score 1):

**Problemas**

- Cuando le das a ok con un campo vacío da error, ya que es un campo
  vacío. Deberías inicializar.
- Si pones 1 siempre da 0, y da error.
- Da error cuando se genera 0 ya que generaría el array "arreglo" con 0
  elementos "cantidad". Por lo que no se pueden insertar elementos.
- Tienes 3 variables para lo mismo: numero, cantidad y rango. Con la
  variable número es suficiente.
- SetText, machaca el contenido anterior.

**Motivos**

- Cuando le das a Math.random()*NUM_ENTERO genera un número en el rango [0,NUM_ENTERO - 1]
- El método ordenar no repite los números, es la función btnOrdenarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) la que funciona mal

**Soluciones**

- después de generar el número, hacer

  - numero++;
- Así se generaría un número del rango [1, NUM_ENTERO] y se evitaría generar un array de 0 elementos. Siempre sería de almenos 1 elemento.
- Se puede hacer un getText y luego añadir o bien hacer un string auxiliar y meter el contenido después del for.

***Mi solución***

```
package OrdenamientoBurbuja;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class OrdenamientoBurbuja extends javax.swing.JFrame {
int arreglo[];



public OrdenamientoBurbuja() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}



public void Ordenamiento(){
    int numero;
    int i, j, k;
    String auxiliar;
    /*Así creamos un valor aleatorio entre [0 y NUM_ENTERO - 1*/
    numero = (int) (Math.random()*Integer.parseInt(this.txtNumero.getText()));
    /*Añadiendo 1 el rango queda [1 y NUM_ENTERO*/
    numero++;

    //Se genera un array de al menos 1 elemento
    arreglo = new int[numero];

    //Generamos un valor aleatorio en el primer lugar del array
    arreglo[0] = (int)(Math.random()*numero);
    System.err.println("Número: " + numero + " - Arreglo:" + arreglo[0]);

    //Se generan nuevos valores si el array es mayor que 1
    for(i = 1; i < numero; i++){
        //System.err.println("Número: " + numero);
        arreglo[i] = (int)(Math.random()*numero);

        //Si el valor generado está repetido se decrementa el contador para generar uno nuevo
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if(arreglo[i] == arreglo[j])
                i--;
    }

    auxiliar = "";
    for(k = 0; k < numero; k++){
        System.out.println("k+1=" + (k+1)+ " " + "arreglo[" + k + "] = " + arreglo[k]);
        auxiliar += (k+1) + " - " + arreglo[k] + "\n";
    }

    this.numSinOrdenar.setText(auxiliar);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtNumero = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    btnOK = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnOrdenar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    numOrdenados = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
    jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    numSinOrdenar = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Introducir cantidad:");

    btnOK.setText("Ok");
    btnOK.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnOKActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnOrdenar.setText("Ordenar");
    btnOrdenar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnOrdenarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(numOrdenados);

    jScrollPane3.setViewportView(numSinOrdenar);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(txtNumero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 118, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(btnOK))
                        .addComponent(btnOrdenar))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(6, 6, 6)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(txtNumero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnOK))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnOrdenar)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 194, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    this.Ordenamiento();
    this.txtNumero.setText("");
}                                     

/**
 * Ordenamos los valores generados en el array de arreglos según su valor
 * pero también queremos saber su posición original, es por esto que hacemos
 * uso de la clase conversión para almacenar el valor y la posición original.
 * 
 * Utilizamos ArrayList en vez de array ya que es más sencillo su manejo
 *
 */
private void btnOrdenarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String auxiliar = "";
    ArrayList<Conversion> aux = new ArrayList();

    int i, j;
    int min;
    int reps;
    int eliminar;

    //Guardamos los valores y las posiciones originales en el objeto auxiliar
    for(i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++)
        aux.add(new Conversion(arreglo[i], i));

    //Se va a repetir tantos elementos hayan en el array
    reps = aux.size() - 1;
    for(i = 0; i <= reps; i++){
        //cojemos siempre el primer valor como el mínimo y se comprueba si no hay otro menor
        min = (int) aux.get(0).getValor();
        eliminar = 0;
        for(j = 1; j < aux.size(); j++){
            if(aux.get(j).getValor() < min){
                min = aux.get(j).getValor();
                eliminar = j;
            }   
        }
        //Se concatena la posicion y el valor en el String auxiliar 
        auxiliar += aux.get(eliminar).getLugar() + " - " + aux.get(eliminar).getValor() + "\n";
        //Se elimina el valor del arraylist auxiliar
        aux.remove(eliminar);
    }
    //Cuando se han eliminado todos los elementos se muestra el resultado
     this.numOrdenados.setText(auxiliar);

}                



public static void main(String args[]) {

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OrdenamientoBurbuja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OrdenamientoBurbuja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OrdenamientoBurbuja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OrdenamientoBurbuja.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new OrdenamientoBurbuja().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnOK;
private javax.swing.JButton btnOrdenar;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
private javax.swing.JTextPane numOrdenados;
private javax.swing.JTextPane numSinOrdenar;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtNumero;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Y una clase adicional

```
package OrdenamientoBurbuja;

public class Conversion {
    private int valor;
    private int lugar;

    public Conversion(int valor, int lugar) {
        this.valor = valor;
        this.lugar = lugar + 1;
    }

    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public int getLugar() {
        return lugar;
    }

    public void setLugar(int lugar) {
        this.lugar = lugar + 1;
    }


}
```

Esta es una posible solución, no digo que sea la mejor, es más hay cosas que se pueden mejorar. Podrías usar un algoritmo de ordenación mejor.